# DPDK: compilation error while freeing MBUF

Tags: dpdk, streambuf

I am trying a simple MBUF create from an allocated pool and freeing the MBUF, however running into the following compilation issues.. If I comment out the mbuf_free, the program compiles fine.. Any pointers please ?

Code :

```
        m = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(pktmbuf_pool);
        if (m == NULL)
            printf("Cannot allocate mbuf");
        if (rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(m) != 0)
            printf("Bad length");

        data = rte_pktmbuf_append(m, packet_len);
        if (data == NULL)
            printf("Cannot append data");
       
        ....

        rte_pktmbuf_free(packet_data_mbuf); <<<<< COMPLAINS here
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h: In function ‘__rte_pktmbuf_free_direct’:
/usr/local/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h:595:64: error: ‘__builtin_ia32_palignr128’ needs isa option -m32 -mssse3
         _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)((uint8_t *)dst + 0 * 16), _mm_alignr_epi8(xmm1, xmm0, offset));        \
                                                                ^
/usr/local/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h:644:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47_IMM’
     case 0x01: MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47_IMM(dst, src, n, 0x01); break;    \
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h:798:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47’
  MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47(dst, src, n, srcofs);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
......
......
```

Comment: from the compiler error it states ` error: ‘__builtin_ia32_palignr128’ needs isa option -m32 -mssse3` are building with custom cflags? Which DPDK version are you using?

Comment: Thanks ! that precisely worked !! Adding -mssse3 into the CFLAGs

Comment: Good to hear it has helped, please accept or upvote to close the question and help the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPDK API `__rte_pktmbuf_free_direct` makes use of SIMD intrinsics `_mm_alignr_epi8`. this internally relies on `palignr`  which are part of `SSSE3` instruction set.

based on the compiler message  `error: ‘__builtin_ia32_palignr128’ needs ISA option -m32 -mssse3`, it appears the compiler flag of `-mssse3` is not passed during built.

Solution: update the CFLAGS with minimum DPDK requirement of `-mssse3` for x86 platform.

Note: If the dpdk version is greater than 19.08, for either custom installed or distro released libdpdk, a simple way to set the right flags is to set `CFGLAGS+=$(pkg-config --cflags libdpdk)`

Comment: Hi Vipin - thanks much, adding -mssse3 in the CFLAGs, solved this issue !!